# Spring Boot Thymeleaf Parsing Error on index.html under src/main/resources/templates/

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm learning Spring Boot. I'm following some online tutorial and I'm trying to create a small login/register Spring Boot web application using Spring Tool Suite IDE with Thymeleaf.
I read online that Thymeleaf should automatically look under `src/main/resources/templates/` folder of the Spring project.

**PROBLEM / Error:**

`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")`

`Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Could not parse as expression: "" (template: "index" - line 13, col 16)`

I put my **index.html** under `src/main/resources/templates/index.html` with the following html code

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Welcome to CodeJava Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1>Welcome to CodeJava.net</h1>
        <h3><a th:href="">List of Users</a></h3>
        <h3><a th:href="">Register</a></h3>
        <h3><a th:href="">Login</a></h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I have an **AppController** class that returns the `index.html` view. I noticed it is using `@GetMapping` with blank `""` string which I assume should point to root and scan an html file with the name **index**

```
package com.jordan.codejava.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.jordan.codejava.repos.UserRepository;

@Controller
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;
     
    @GetMapping("")
    public String viewHomePage() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**UserRepository** is just an interface extending JpaRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{}
```

I even tried to replace **@GetMapping("")** with `@GetMapping("/")` or `@RequestMapping("")` or `@RequestMapping(value = "/")` but I still get the same error message.

I searched online but still can't find a solution.

Do I need to specify the view prefix in this case? Something like,

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
```

in the application.properties file?

I'd appreciate any suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: No you don't need to specify the view prefix. You're getting the problem while parsing the index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a valid Thymeleaf expression:

```
th:href=""
```

If you want an empty value, you can just use a non-Thymeleaf attribute, without the `th` prefx:

```
href=""
```

Or if you want Thymeleaf to generate an empty string, you can use something like this:

```
th:href="''"
```

But more typically I would expect to see a full `@{...}` Thymeleaf expression using the [link URL](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#link-urls) syntax.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. In the process of running the app and changing the href part, I encountered the `Whitelabel Error page, This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback` error. Fortunately I found several solutions via google. 

Adding this link as reference for others
https://www.yawintutor.com/application-has-no-explicit-mapping-for-error-whitelabel-error-page-with-status-404/

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
<a th:href="">
```

is invalid Thymeleaf expression.

Use `<a th:href= "@{/some_kind_of_link}">`

Only then Thymeleaf will understand you. When you put `<a th:href="">` Thymeleaf doesn't know what to do and then he can't render the webpage, so he shows an error.